# Unparseable date: 07/23/1975

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android application with Android SDK 4.2, and target Android 2.2.

I get this exception:

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 07/23/1975

Here:

```
try
{
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy", Locale.US);
    convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(userBirthday);
}
catch (ParseException  ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
    convertedDate = null;
}
```

When `userBirthday` is 07/23/1975.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Your date has **slashes** , your format string doesn't have any ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
```

---

However, note that a significant percentage of the worlds population think that the user's birthday ought to be written as "23/07/1975" ... or something else.

You should be using looking up the preferred format in the locale.  Look at the documentation for the static `getXxx(...)` methods in [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html).  (If this in an Android app, the platform's default locale is probably the right one.)

Comment: What a shame! It was so easy see that I forget slashes! Thanks.

Comment: What does '`You should be using looking up the format in the locale.`' means?

Answer (score 3):

Change format to:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 1):

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution:

```
try
{
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
    convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(userBirthday);
}
catch (ParseException  ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
    convertedDate = null;
}
```